# What is the French phrase (or hyphenated word) for describing frivolities?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am trying to think of a particular term that is used to refer to the frivolous, inconsequential activities of the rich and idle. I keep thinking of "fee-fees of the rich" for some reason, but googling "fee-fees" pulls up nothing. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're after a French phrase this might not be the best place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You possibly mean the English word (obviously from the French) **froufrou**.

> **froufrou** noun (or frou-frou)
>
> plural froufrous or frou-frous
>
> - 1  a rustling especially of a woman's skirts
> - 2  showy or frilly ornamentation
>
> **froufrou** adjective
>
> variants: or frou-frou
>
> : very showy or fancy … *fussy, fragile, froufrou clothes won't make
>   it through the winter.*

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/froufrou)]

Comment: Note that "frou-frou" is extremely rare other than as a name for heroines in 19th and early 20th century literature. Google Ngrams: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=frou&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrou%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfrou%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to recall the French *frou-frou*.

Its basic meaning seems to be onomatopeoic - representing the rustle of fancy dresses as their affluent wearers walked about in the late 19th century.  So the Cambridge English defines it as:

> decorative pieces added to women's clothing:

The Merriam Webster offer a short article:

> Nineteenth-century Europe featured a lot of sophisticated fashions—especially in Paris, a city considered by many to be the fashion capital of the world. Women's dresses were often made of drooping layers of fabric (such as satin or silk) that rustled as the women moved around, and "froufrou" was the French word coined in imitation of the sound they made. The word made its first appearance in English in 1870 as a noun meaning "rustling." It later came to mean "ostentatious decoration," and its usage expanded beyond the world of fashion to other crafts such as architecture and interior design. These days it also shows up as the adjective frou-frou, meaning "very heavily decorated and fancy," as in "frou-frou designs."